# Как заменить конструкцию if-elseif

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Есть страница с ограниченым доступом. Для каждой роли - свои данные , которые формируем запросами.
Получается примерно вот такая конструкция

```
if (Yii::$app->accessControl->isRoot()) {
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => User::find(),
            ]);
        }
        elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isDirector()){
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => User::find()
                ->where(['NOT IN', 'id', [1]]),
            ]);
        }
        elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isManager()){
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => User::accessManager()
            ]);
        }
        else {
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => User::accessAdministrator()
            ]);
        }
```

Подскажите, можно ли каким-то способом сделать этот код по культурней?)

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом ? Этот не культурный код ругается матом?) 
Ну замените if на switch. Или вы ищете Design Pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Если самый простой код и не вникать в то что происходит в методах, то я бы сделал так:

```
if (Yii::$app->accessControl->isRoot()) {
    $query = User::find();
}
elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isDirector()){
    $query = User::find()->where(['NOT IN', 'id', [1]]);
}
elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isManager()){
    $query = User::accessManager();
}
else {
    $query = User::accessAdministrator();
}

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

Можно было бы ещё всю эту логику в метод перенести по типу:

```
public function index() {
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $this->getUsersQuery();
    ]);
}

protected function getUsersQuery() {
    if (Yii::$app->accessControl->isRoot()) {
        $query = User::find();
    }
    elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isDirector()){
        $query = User::find()->where(['NOT IN', 'id', [1]]);
    }
    elseif (Yii::$app->accessControl->isManager()){
        $query = User::accessManager();
    }
    else {
        $query = User::accessAdministrator();
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Но т.к. нет данных в целом, то можно только чуть упростить вывод

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать такой приём со switch:

```
switch (true) {
    case Yii::$app->accessControl->isRoot():
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => User::find(), ]);
        break;
    case Yii::$app->accessControl->isDirector():
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => User::find() ->where(['NOT IN', 'id', [1]]), ]);
        break;
    case Yii::$app->accessControl->isManager():
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => User::accessManager() ]);
        break;
    default:
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => User::accessAdministrator() ]);
        break;
}
```

Получается довольно наглядно, похоже на человеческий язык, удобно писать комментарии. Подталкивает к тому, чтобы писать короткие человекочитаемые условия в case (если условие длинное/сложное - выносим в отдельный метод).